# Jest - testing Link (next/link)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I am trying to write unit tests to confirm my nav links work correctly.
My `MainNavigation.js` file:

```
import Link from 'next/link';

const MainNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <div>
        <Link href='/'>The React Parks</Link>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link href='/all-parks'>All Parks</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href='/new-park'>Add a New Park</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
};

export default MainNavigation;
```

My test file:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import MainNavigation from './MainNavigation';

describe('MainNavigation', () => {
    describe('links', () => {
    jest.mock('next/link', () => ({ children }) => children);

    it('should redirect to '/' when clicking on "The React Parks" text', () => {
      render(<MainNavigation />);

      const parksString = screen.getByText('The React Parks');
      fireEvent.click(parksString);
      expect(parksString.closest('link')).toHaveAttribute('href', 'https://');
    })
  });
});
```

How can I maybe include checking if the URL matches certain string? Or would it make sense to do something like assign a constant to render different pages and expect that constant to match some text on the other pages? How would one go about testing this functionality?

Comment: Testing links navigate correctly to the expected page should by done at the end-to-end testing level. If what you want is to test that the link it present in the DOM, then simply use queries to look for the element.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using

```
jest.mock(
  'next/link',
  () =>
    ({ children, ...rest }: { children: ReactElement }) =>
      React.cloneElement(children, { ...rest }),
);
```

That way, the `push` function of `next/link` does not fail and the `href` from `next/link` is passed to your child component

Comment: This gives the error `The module factory of \`jest.mock()\` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables. Invalid variable access: React`

Comment: To get around the variable access issue, you can require the actual module in the mock:

`jest.mock("next/link", () => {  const { cloneElement } = jest.requireActual("react"); return ({ children, ...rest }: LinkProps) => cloneElement(children, { ...rest }); });`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get a reply, but I kind of achieved what I wanted by testing with a snapshot:

```
describe('Links', () => {
    const links = [
      <Link href='/'>The React Parks</Link>,
      <Link href='/all-parks'>All Parks</Link>,
      <<Link href='/new-park'>Add a New Park</Link>
    ]
    it('render correctly', () => {
      const tree = renderer.create(links).toJSON();

      expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
jest.mock('next/link', () => props => require('react').createElement('div', props))
```